# How can I make imports less repetitive in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-17

Instead of copying and pasting the same import statements in every single class file is there a way to put all of the imports you need on just one file and then call that file  for example instead of pasting this every time:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
```

could you somehow put those statements in just one file and then import that instead ie.

```
import My_Imports;
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. As your question is tagged with IntelliJ, did you have a look at [IntelliJ's auto import feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html)?

Comment: If you use an IDE, they automate some of that tedium. i.e. eclipse: Ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: Why? Your IDE manages all this for you, you don't need to think about it.  Besides, it's fairly uncommon for the same set of imports to be needed everywhere.

Comment: Does every single one of your classes need an IOException? Does this have anything to do with intellij-idea? I haven't written an import statement in idea in years.

Comment: Having too many imports might also be a sign that your class is too big. Consider splitting the code in several classes if you find a meaningful way to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen it done like that. I don't think it is possible but even if it was, I don't see that as very readable code. It doesn't tell me everything I need to know without me having to visit the package where all the imports are.

I believe the only ways to import packages are to use the very specifc naming conventions i.e.

`import java.util.List;`

or to import a whole package

`import java.util.*;`

Comment: If you are on IntelliJ though, you can check out your preferences and make sure auto imports are on